# insert data during runtime

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

I have created students attendance management database. I have used `sql server` and `VB12`. My problem is I have created 2 datasets from my table. One dataset have register no and name. and other have register no, name,attendance ,total and percent. I successfully added reg no and name using first dataset.using second dataset i have to enter the attendance and find its total and percent for the newly created register no. when i enter the attendance and click my add button I receive a error msg tat + operator is not defined for db null.
I have two button connect and add. My code for buttons are,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\studentattendance\studentattendance\attnd\details.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "select * from entry"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            connection.Close()
            EntryDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            MsgBox("connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    connetionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\studentattendance\studentattendance\attnd\details.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    sql = "select * from entry"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(7) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8)
            ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(10) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9) / 7
        Next
        adapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
        connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Data updated ! ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try


End Sub
```

please help me...

Comment: are you getting error on this line `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(9) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(7) + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(8)` ?

Comment: if the field is `integer` then use `val(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))` elseif `string` use `tostring` i.e `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).Tostring`

Comment: Regarding the error message you mention, do you understand what `DBNull` is? If not, did you look it up?

Answer (score 2):

> ***"+ operator is not defined for db null."***

It's indeed *not* defined.

You need to check if the field contains a [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) value.

```
IsDBNull(ds.Tables(n).Rows(n).Item(n))
```

For instance, if the 3'rd and 4'th column has the data type set to Integer:

```
Dim item2 As Object = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2)
Dim item3 As Object = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3)

Dim result As Integer = (
    If(IsDBNull(item2), 0I, CInt(item2)) + 
    If(IsDBNull(item3), 0I, CInt(item3))
)
```

You should turn [`Option Strict ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) ASAP as this will prevent you from doing this kind of mistakes in the future.